# Cairo test if text overlaps

Tags: drawing, cairo

Using Cairo, I'm placing some text at random positions, and I need to know if they overlap some previously drawn arbitrary shapes. I could clip the path to the previous drawings, and if any clipping occurs it means that there is overlap. However, Cairo doesn't seem to have any functions to tell if clipping did occur or not.

Is there any way to easily accomplish what I want? I guess I just basically want to see if two shapes intersect or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using Qt for the rendering instead. It seems to have quite extensive support for different path operations and supports both PDF and SVG output.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the quality you want to get, you can use `cairo_stroke_extents`, `cairo_fill_extents` and `cairo_text_extents` and work on the boundary boxes.

A better approach would be to compute only the boundary box of the text and check the four corners against the last path with `cairo_in_fill` or `cairo_in_stroke`. The maximum error would be the distance from the shape of a single glyph to its bounding box but maybe this is enough for your purpose.

The last option would be to flatten the text and check any single point as in the previous step.

Comment: Your suggestion is not precise enough, as such. But thanks for pointing to cairo_in_stroke. By adjusting the width of the stroke to match the dimensions of the text bounding box, a suitably fast and solid mechanism can be made. See below for my further answer on that. And thanks for the pointer. :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything - at least, nothing simple - and I wouldn't be surprised if there weren't anything. Cairo is aimed at rasterizing vector drawing operations, not intersection testing.

However, if I were going to see if two pieces of text overlapped, here's what I would do:

1. Pick a Cairo backend suitable to my
   test environment - e.g. Xlib, etc. -
   and use an offscreen surface that I
   can use to do a pixel-by-pixel
   analysis.
2. Draw the first piece of text in solid blue with 100% alpha.
3. Draw the second piece of text in solid red with 50% alpha.
4. Scan the surface for pixels where both red and blue are non-zero.

It's rather brute force, but it will even cope with anti-aliasing. I've done something like that before (for a different purpose) with GTK on X, which indirectly uses Cairo.

If you don't want to do it that way, and Cairo doesn't provide an API, you might be able to add one. That would probably be difficult; you might want to talk with Carl Worth before doing that.

Comment: Well, there is a lot of intersection checking code in Cairo, that's what clipping is all about, right? The code is definitely there, it's just not exposed to users. I'm going to go with a raster-based work-around like you suggest, but it does still seem a bit silly.

Oh, and Cairo is not just aimed at rasterization, it outputs vector formats just fine too. I'd say Cairo is a vector-based drawing library, and having to go via raster-images to accomplish some simple things seems a bit silly.

Comment: pafcu, I agree that the raster image route is inelegant. But depending on requirements, sometimes a workable-but-inelegant solution is preferable, if it's faster to implement. I occasionally need to dispose of hard drives and need to make sure that sensitive data they've contained cannot be read. The elegant-but-time consuming approach is a 7x or 35x rewrite with random data. Instead, I just take them to my concrete patio and hit them a few times with a sledge hammer or pickaxe.

Comment: Bob, can you please remind me which Cairo API provides that pixel-by-pixel iteration. I have the memory it's there but couldn't find it.  ADDENDUM: it's cairo_image_surface_get_data()

Answer (score 0):

I have an almost identical situation and I think there's a way to do this.

My issue is finding whether a text bounding box intersects with a complex set of lines (maybe smoothened) drawn on a surface. This is currently a bottleneck and fast intersection handling would speed the sw by maybe 100x. Who knows.

Anyways, thanks to ntd's mention of [cairo_in_stroke](http://www.cairographics.org/manual/cairo-cairo-t.html#cairo-in-stroke) I began to twist the issue around. Here's the thing.

cairo_in_stroke itself only tells

> "whether the given point is inside the
>   area that would be affected by a
>   cairo_stroke() operation given the
>   current path and stroking parameters"

This is pretty useless. Unless we make the line width temporarily so wide that the path starts gaining area.

1. set line width to half the height of the bounding box (let's call this X)
2. test positions X,2X,... into the bounding box from both sides, until they meet in the center

The tested area is not precisely the bounding box but an overlapping chain of circles approximating it. If you want to be on the safe side, adding line width will make sure the bounding box really is never touched.

I will report if I got this method to actually do the trick (and how fast it became).